# Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharp, Version=1.2.1269.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

Unable to use latest version of pdfsharp download from [Codeplex](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases). Getting below error. Please suggest solution. [image]